# Why does my I18n function throw an exception under the test environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

I have the following in `config/initializers/i18n.rb`:

```
module I18n
  def self.name_for_locale(locale)
    I18n.backend.translate(locale, "i18n.language.name")  #this is line 4
  rescue I18n::MissingTranslation
    locale.to_s
  end
end
```

I use it in a view like so (I'm using slim templates):

```
I18n.available_locales.each do |locale|
  option value="#{ locale.to_sym }" selected=(@current_user.locale.to_sym == locale.to_sym)
    = I18n.name_for_locale(locale)
```

Everything works great in development/production.  But it throws an error while integration testing.  I get the following:

```
uncaught throw :exception
@ /Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:37:in `throw'
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/i18n-0.6.9/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:37:in `translate'
config/initializers/i18n.rb:4:in `name_for_locale'
```

Here's an example of one of my `en.yml` file:

```
en:
  i18n:
    language:
      name: 'Americas'
  date:
    formats:
      default: ! '%m-%d-%Y'
      long: ! '%B %d, %Y'
```

What is the proper way for me to get the name of each locale as I'm trying to do above?  Or how can I prevent the error from being thrown in the test environment?